# Fetch API not working with localhost/127.0.0.1

Tags: reactjs, amazon-ec2, fetch

Just as background, I have a react app sitting on a remote EC2 Ubuntu instance. The same server also runs a Go app listening on port 8080 (port has been opened to everyone from the Security settings).

I am trying to make a request with Fetch API, from the React app, as follows:

```
var bearer = 'Bearer ...'
return fetch('http://localhost:8080/home', {
  headers: new Headers({
    'Authorization': bearer
  })
})
```

In the console, from both Chrome and Firefox, I am getting:

**TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource**

The same goes when I substitute `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`.

Using the external IP of the EC2 instance, however, works (and triggers a CORS request - due to the 'Authorization' header - which is handled smoothly by the server).

In the latter case, I can also see the server logging the incoming request for both OPTIONS and GET (in the former case, no logs are present for either method).

I also tried CURL'ing from the EC2 machine to `localhost` and the request effectively goes through which leads me to think that with the Fetch API the request is not triggered at all.

Any advice would be appreciated. If I am doing anything wrong please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Which url you use in your browser in order to open the page (that does the actual fetch request)?

Comment: I am using the external IP address of the EC2 instance (port 80), the same IP address where the successful Fetch request is directed to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you write `localhost` it calls your (localhost) machine (on which the browser is present) because the `js` code is running in your browser.

You should create a domain/sub-domain for your API endpoint and use it instead of localhost or continue to use the hard-coded IP address.

You should also allow only your frontend website domain in the allowed origins for your backend. Ex. your website can be `www.example.com` and backend url can be `www.api.example.com`. You should allow only `www.example.com` as the `origin` which can be served through `www.api.example.com`. You will need to configure this in the backend.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Although this may be more appropriate for another question I'd like to ask, how would you go about keeping the same configuration between the local development machine (using localhost) and the remote production machine (not able to use localhost) if at all possible?

Comment: I use two environments.  Basically keep a `webkpack.config.js` and `webpack.config.prod.js`. And use DefinePlugin in webpack to define your backend subdomain. In `prod` config, use subdomain and in dev config, use localhost. Also, I allow all origins in my backend in dev mode.

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I was hoping for.

Comment: This is not an answer. The question is how to make it work with localhost for local development, not how to circumvent the problem in the most obvious way.

Answer (score 21):

I just had the same problem. I managed to get this working by adding `"proxy": "http://localhost:4000"` to `package.json`.

Then you can write requests like `fetch('/api/todos')`.

They explain it good [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development).

Comment: Remember to restart servers!

Answer (score 8):

If you're trying to send a request to localhost, and you are hosting your server on localhost, then you don't need to specify the url, you only need to tell `fetch()` your path.

For example, my api end point is `http://localhost:8082/api/config`, then i would do `fetch('/api/config')`.

Here is a link to `fetch` method, [link](https://github.github.io/fetch/)

Comment: This doesn't work if the `fetch` call is coming from a different project and running from a different port number, such as 2 different instances of VS.

Answer (score 1):

For me it wasn't working with OperaGX. Switching to firefox/google chrome fixed it.